# Where to put own document class .cls file for Tex Live 2016

Tags: latex, tex, tex-live

I understand that there are similar questions posted on stack overflow and elsewhere. But after a couple of trials and failures, I thought this could be a new version of an old question.

So with TexStudio 2.9.4 + Tex Live 2016 with Windows 10 system, my little project is to create my CV with a document class file `res.cls`.

I was told to put it under:
1.  `C:\Users\<user>\.texlive2016\textmf-config\textworks\scripts\LaTex Style`, or some variations of it depending on what system. Yet, there is no folder like `.\texlive2016` under `C:\Users\<user>`.

2. the texlive folder, which in my case is `D:\Program files\texlive\textmf-local\tex\latex\local`. It sounds sensible, yet not working.

Then I start to wonder if there's anything wrong with my editor. I switched from Tex Live 2015 to 2016, because there's no package update for 2015 version. Yet, I've reconfigured the Tex Studio to Tex Live 2016 (two red circles in the image below).

[image: Latex Problem]

Is there anything wrong? Any thoughts? Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess you are using a template, a complete zip? Don't move anything anywhere and it will work.

Comment: Word of advice: Don t use `res.cls`. It was designed in the mid-eighties.

Comment: @Johannes_B It worked when I put it under the same folder of `.tex` file! Thanks! So you mean `res.cls` is out of fashion?

Comment: @Johannes_B And why in `Tex Live 2015`, it used to be put under the `C:\Users\<user>\.texlive2016\textmf-config\textworks\scripts\LaTex Style`?

Comment: Stuff *lives* on CTAN (hence TeX Live) forever. But ... it is really obsolete.

Comment: Personally, i recommend to start from scratch. If a HR guy gets ten CVs and nine of them look the same ... I know what is going to pick.

Comment: @Johannes_B Interesting. Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 1):

Execute `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` which should give you `c:\Users\<usr>\texmf`.

Then install into `tex\latex\<somedir>\`, for example `...\local\`.

.cls files are searched under `tex\latex`